# Problemas con el Menu para declarar un array del objeto SalaDeCine C++

Tags: c++

¿como le hago para hacer que entre a menuSala seleccione La Sala indicada y se llenen el vector?.

Se que tengo que declarar un array para las salas y estes se llenen y vacien a voluntad del usuario pero no se como hacer que sea funcional entre objetos

Aqui les paso el codigo.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

class SalaDeCine
{
    private:
        string NombrePelicula;
        string Clasificacion;                                                                         
        int Asientos[5][9] {};
    public:
        void CarteleraSala();
        void asignarButaca();
        void eliminarButaca();
        void mostrarSala();
        void vaciarSala();  
};

class MenuSala
{
private:
    SalaDeCine sala;
public:
    void AsignarSala( SalaDeCine );
    void MenuPrincipal();
    void MenuPrincipalSala();
};
//Metodos de SalaDeCine
void SalaDeCine::asignarButaca()
{
char letra;
int num;
cout << "\n\nintroduzca la posicion con la letra A,B,C para filas y numeros para columnas ASIGNAR ASIENTO" << endl;
cout << "introduzca letra y numero:";
cin >> letra >> num;


if(letra >= 'A' and letra <= 'E')
{
    letra -= 65;
    Asientos[static_cast<int> (letra)][num] = true;

}
else if(letra >= 'a' and letra <= 'e')
{
    letra -= 97;
    Asientos[static_cast<int> (letra)][num]= true;
}

}//fin de metodo
void SalaDeCine::eliminarButaca()
{

        char letra;
        int num;
        cout << "\n\nintroduzca la posicion con la letra A,B,C para filas y numeros para columnas ELIMINAR ASIENTO" << endl;
        cout << "introduzca letra y numero:";
        cin >> letra >> num;


        if(letra >= 'A' and letra <= 'E')
        {
            letra -= 65;
            Asientos[static_cast<int> (letra)][num] = false;

        }
        else if(letra >= 'a' and letra <= 'e')
        {
            letra -= 97;
            Asientos[static_cast<int> (letra)][num] = false;
        }
    //fin de metodo
}
void SalaDeCine::mostrarSala()
{
        char letra;
        letra = 65;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8"<< endl;
        cout << "  +-------------------------+"<< endl;
    for(int fil = 0; fil < 5; fil++)
        {
            cout<< (static_cast<char>(fil + letra)) << " ";
            for(int col = 0; col < 9; col++)
            {
            cout<<"|"<< Asientos[fil][col] << "|";
            }
        cout << endl;
        }
        cout << "  +-------------------------+"<< endl;
    cout << endl;
}//fin de metodo

void SalaDeCine::vaciarSala()
{
        int Asientos[5][9];

        for(int fil = 0; fil < 5; fil++)
        {
            for(int col = 0; col < 9; col++)
            {
            Asientos[fil][col] = false;
            cout << Asientos[fil][col] << " ";
            }
        cout << endl;
        }
}//fin de metodo

//metodo de MenuSala
void MenuSala::MenuPrincipalSala()
{

        int opcion;

        cout << "Menu de Sala:\n";
        cout << "+--------------------------------+\n";
        cout << "|1.-Asignar Butaca               |\n";
        cout << "|2.-Eliminar Butaca              |\n";
        cout << "|3.-Mostrar Sala                 |\n";
        cout << "|4.-Vaciar Sala                  |\n";
        cout << "|5.-Salir al Menu Principal      |\n";
        cout << "+--------------------------------+\n";
        cin >> opcion;
        system("clear");
        switch(opcion)
        {
            case 1:
                sala.asignarButaca();
                MenuPrincipalSala();
                break;
            case 2:
                sala.eliminarButaca();
                MenuPrincipalSala();
                break;
            case 3:
                sala.mostrarSala();
                MenuPrincipalSala();
                break;
            case 4:
                sala.vaciarSala();
                MenuPrincipalSala();
                break;
            case 5:
                MenuPrincipal();
                break;
        }
}
void MenuSala::MenuPrincipal()
{
int opcion;

        cout << "Menu de Principal:\n";
        cout << "+--------------------------------+\n";
        cout << "|1.-Seleccionar Sala             |\n";
        cout << "|2.-Mostrar Salas                |\n";
        cout << "|3.-Mostrar Funciones            |\n";
        cout << "|4.-Salir del Programa           |\n";
        cout << "+--------------------------------+\n";
        cin >> opcion;
        system("clear");
        switch(opcion)
        {
        case 1:
            int num;
            cout << "Sala 0" << endl;
            cout << "Sala 1" << endl;
            cout << "Sala 2" << endl;
            cout << "Elige el numero de la sala: "; 
            cin >> num;
            //Como haria aqui para seleccionar la sala
            MenuPrincipalSala();
            AsignarSala( sala );
            break;
        case 2:
            for(int n = 0; n < 3; n++) 
            {
            cout << "Sala: " << n << endl;
            }
            MenuPrincipal();
            break;
        case 3:

            MenuPrincipal();
            break;
        case 4:
        system("exit");
            break;
        }
}

void MenuSala::AsignarSala( SalaDeCine)
{
    MenuPrincipalSala();
}
int main()
{
MenuSala Menu;
Menu.MenuPrincipal();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: como hacer funcional dentro de la clase o hacerlo funcional en el Menu. sala[] un array y yo poder  seleccionar la sala del cine que que deseo.